# Session_start causes 500 ERROR

Tags: php

I have been working on website (Yii + angularJs) and everything was okey. 
Then I decided to work at home and cloned repository to my laptop. 
And then a problem appeared.

Website doesn't give any resources or files to display, just white screen and error 500 (Internal Server Error) appears with no reasons or explanations. 
And only when I comment some lines in Main Controller everything goes okey.
I comment session_start() function and checks of users rigths from $_Session array.
Example below.
(Note, if I leave  session_start() line, site loads index page with login form, then I fill fields and then white screen again)

```
public function actionIndex() {
        $page = safe($_GET,'page','index');
    $pages = $this->get_pages();
        $pageInfo = safe($pages,$page);
    //session_start();
        if(safe($pageInfo,'layout')) {
            $this->layout = $pageInfo['layout'];
        }
        if($page == 'reset-password') {
            $params = array_change_key_case($_GET, CASE_UPPER);
            if(!isset($params['RECOVERY_TOKEN']))
                $this->redirect('/');
        } else if($page == 'request') {
            $id = safe($_GET, 'id');
            if(!$id || !$this->validID($page, $id)) {
                $this->redirect('/requests');
            }
        }
      $this->render(safe($pageInfo,'render',$page)); //moved from comments below
      /*if($_SESSION['rights'][$page] && !$_SESSION['rights'][$page]['show']){
      $this->redirect('/dashboard');
    }else {
      try {
        if (!safe($pageInfo,'layout') && empty($_SESSION) && $pages[$page]) {
          $this->redirect('/');
        }else{
          $this->render(safe($pageInfo,'render',$page));
        }
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new CHttpException(404);
      }
    }*/
  }
```

Strange is that after login to website I also have session_start() function, but this one doesn't cause such error.
And also, i have no problems with my code on my work computer and on dev-server. 
We have tried to clone this site to another laptop, the same error appeared.

I have no ideas what is wrong. Please, help. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using `session_start()` in the function, call it at the start of the *`php`* page, directly after the opening `<?php` tag and befoer any other data is output

Comment: I have tried but still the same error and white screen

Comment: Is this code part of a class or a function by itself?

Comment: it is a part of class. In class are also function that gets pages of site and some that render pages with ID or 404 error page